# jquery filter element classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, filter, onclick

i have current html code:

```
<ul id="test">
  <li class="apple cat active"></li>
  <li class="apple dog"></li>
  <li class="apple bear"></li>
</ul>
```

then i have a onclick listener

```
$('.apple').bind('click',function(){
  alert($(this).attr('class'));
  postClassname(...);
});
```

i want to filter the specified repeated class name

```
eg:
"apple bear" > "bear"
"apple dog" > "dog"
"apple hover xyz fox abc123" > "fox"
"apple active cat" > "cat"
```

and the class name order maybe dynamic

then pass the filtered class name to postClassname() function

in postClassname function:

```
function postClassname(class){
  switch(class){
    case 'fox':
       alert('selected fox');
    break;
  }
}
```

how can i achieve that?

Comment: Is it always the second class you want?

Comment: no,the order maybe random

Comment: And there can be 1..n classes?

Comment: @jkjk: So how do you select `bear`, `dog`, `fox`, and `cat`? JavaScript doesn't have a `.isAnimalName()` method.

Comment: @Blender Read my mind.

Comment: The more you add to your question, the less it makes sense. Quit posting code, and use words to describe what you want, and where you're stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is what you should do
[**DEMO FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/jCjHL/1/)

code --

```
var animalList = ['cat', 'dog', 'bear'];
$('.apple').bind('click',function(){
var classList = $(this).attr('class');
classList= classList.split(" ");
$(classList).each(function(){
    if(animalList.indexOf(this+'') >-1)
        postClassname(this);
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could split up the class name:

```
$('.apple').click(function() {
    var second_class = this.className.split(/\s+/)[1];

    postClassname(second_class);
});
```

Comment: sorry,updated my question